# calling a webservice with jquery that accepts five STRING params?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, web-services, soap

is it possible to call a webservice that accepts 5 string parameters without sending via json? (is this recommended) I have created a webservice with a method that accepts 5 string params.. and i have my jquery

```
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Service.aspx/CreateClient",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //// ERMMM ???
                dataType: "json", // ERMMM?
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('error');
                }

            });
```

The old way without using jquery was to do this

```
            this.para.add("Name", name);
            this.para.add("ClientNum", clnum);
            this.para.add("Email", email);
            this.para.add("Register", register);
            this.para.add("Message", message);

            SOAPClient.invoke(this.url, "MyService.aspx/CreateClient", this.para, true, this.completeDone, this);
```

At the other end it lands and fills in all parameters....

What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use querystring variables and avoid the overhead of the SOAP protocol?